# iTunes opens on event of remote device or app in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-lion, itunes, remote

I was having trouble with iTunes opening once I paired my bluetooth headphones, I was trying to play something off of soundcloud, and every time I hit the button on my headphones or even pressed the play button IN the browser (FF11) it would launch iTunes. TERRIBLE that there is no simple fix in apple's preferences menu in either iTunes or system.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are simple:
Download - http://nomitsu.com/download.php?file=mmfix 
Open DMG
Drag MMFix.app to your applications fold (Leave it here incase you wish to restore this feature)
Double Click
Confirm.

Try using your device or app again.